# Go lang get matching substring from string

Tags: regex, string, go, substring

I'm trying to extract all words from a string which are between quotes.

Here's my current code:

```
func StrExtract(word string) []string {
  r, _ := regexp.Compile(`".*"`)
  result := r.FindAllString(word, -1)
  RemoveDuplicates(&result)
  return (result)
}
```

Test the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/6-_szcjzzJ)

With an input like:

```
`Hi guys, this is a "test" and a "demo" ok?`
```

I get the output:

```
["test" and a "demo"]
```

But I'd like to get:

```
[test demo]
```

Please help me fix this, or suggest better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a lazy quantifier `.*?`, `".*?"` being the regex, if you want to keep it simple. The reason you are getting `"test" and a "demo"` is because just `.*` is greedy and matches as much text as possible (therefore, it actually matches the `"` before `test` and after `demo`, ignoring the fact that there are other quotes in between).

Normally a better but in some ways slightly more complicated way to do this is using character classes `"[^"]*"`, disabling matching quotes in between. This can also cause some other behaviors like including newlines (in which case you can also disable them `[^"\n]`, or perhaps you actually want such a case)

Since you want to also not have the quotes some additional things need to be done. You can do that with either lookarounds: `(?<=")[^"]*(?=")`, or with capture groups: `"(.*?)"` and `"([^"]*)"`. If you choose the capture group route, you have to use the capture group, not whole matches.

Comment: Thanks Andris, it really helps me! nice answer ;-)

Comment: @hiroru, here is another explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754836/golang-use-regex-to-return-the-shortest-string-between-strings/25755502#25755502

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

`"(.*?)"`

Here is an online demo:
https://regex101.com/r/sI4tA9/1

All you have to do now is to join matches. Unfortunately I'm not so into `go` that's why I can't help you in that case

Comment: Thanks Doro, this website it's awesome!